# apache shutdown unexpectedly xampp apache

Tags: apache, xampp

i cant start apache

```
    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
05:35:18 PM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
05:35:18 PM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
05:35:18 PM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
05:35:18 PM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
05:35:18 PM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
05:35:18 PM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

I modified the httpd.conf file and the httpd-ssl.conf file and it didn't work.

Could the problem be with the proxy on the device?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUs03.png)

Comment: Hi please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417). Also, this site is specific for programming-related questions, and maybe your question fits better on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error appears when there are few free resources (CPU, RAM) on the computer, e.g. when system updates are started automatically in the background.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).